# Rugby Mascot question

Tags: riddle

Why is Leo here an appropriate mascot for Leinster Rugby?

[Disclaimer: You're more likely to get this if you're from Ireland]

[image: Leo]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because

> the Irish name of Leinster is Laighin, which is pronounced very similarly to the English word "lion".

Also, more prosaically, because

> the team was formerly known as the Leinster Lions; I don't know whether this is *because* of the sound of "Laighin" but I wouldn't be at all surprised if it were.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's appropriate because

> **Leo** Varadkar is the current Taoiseach (Prime Minister)

Plus

> The seat of the Oireachtas (parliament of Ireland) is **Leinster** House